# geting permission denied error with nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, virtualenv, gunicorn, permission-denied

I'm hosintg a site using django - gunicorn - nginx -virtualenv
but I got 404 error . when I checked nginx error log I got this :

```
   connect() to unix:/webapps/myapp/run/gunicorn.sock failed (13: Permission denied)
```

here is permission for gunicorn.sock :

```
  srwxrwxrwx 1 myappuser webapps    0 Sep  7 22:17 gunicorn.sock
```

I check use that nginx runs with using this command :

```
 ps aux | grep “nginx: worker process” | awk ‘{print $1}’
```

and I got :

```
  nginx
  root
```

could any body help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably installed gunicorn as root, you should reinstall:

```
sudo pip uninstall gunicorn
pip install gunicorn
```

Comment: I install gunicorn inside virtualenv . with myappuser  user